# How can I see the SQL statements executed against my localdb database?

Tags: sql, profiling, localdb

I'm running LocalDB to develop my application and would like to see the SQL statements which are being executed by my application from its various components. Is there a tool I can use to capture these statements?

Comment: It would be nice to know what DB do you use? If MS SQL what edition

Comment: I'm using LocalDB. I'm not sure how much clearer I can be.

Comment: LocalDB is not a DBMS product I have ever heard of. Is it Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: Sorry. Was inattentive. As LocalDB is fully compatible with the other editions of MS SQL I suggest trying to use following sql profiler https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/

Comment: @Oleg You should totally make that an answer - it's helpful and deserves a proper up-vote.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry if it's not obvious. The [tag:localdb] tag contains some basic information about LocalDB. You can think of it as a special flavour of SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio over SQL 2008 or SQL 2008 R2 you have a tool called **Activity Monitor** that allows you to see what queries are being executed against your database along with statictics details like the cost it have for the dbms. You can just get it up doing right click on the server (once you have open Mgmt Sutdio), choose "Activity Monitor" and see "Recent Expensive Queries" section at the end of the app. Good luck.

Comment: Yes. In fact you can filter out results by the database under evaluation in a list of all the databases hosted on SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Let me chime in on two very light-weight Sql profilers that can do the job for various SqlServer flavors, including LocalDb - "*worked on my machine (TM)*"

### ExpressProfiler

By far the easiest to use one (and also the most bare-bones-show-me-the-SQL-statements-kthxbye) is [ExpressProfiler on CodePlex](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/).

[image]

And the whole program is a single 126 KB EXE ! Now that's lightweight!

### AnjLab Sql Profiler

The other one is the one from [DataWizard](http://www.datawizard.com/), which used to be free (apparently prices now start at $5).

Somebody managed to save a [snapshot on GitHub](https://github.com/ren85/free-sql-server-profiler) (including xcopy-installable binaries) when it was open-source.

The executable presents itself as "AnjLab Sql Profiler" and allows some filtering of the displayed events - but this strength is also its weakness, as there are sooo many event types that can be enabled/disabled. If everything is selected, the output is overwhelmingly verbose.

A saner output can be obtained by only selecting specific events.

[image]

Here are the events I have selected in order to get the above output:

[image]